# How to get mysql-server setup on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: dpkg, mysql, 15.04

When I was upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 my mysql somehow broke.

When I run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After a long wait I get the following response

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.24-0ubuntu2) ...
Job for mysql.service failed. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and                     "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.6
mysql-server
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after much help from @kos and google I have managed to get it sorted.

The steps that seemed to work were as follows.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I ran

```
tasksel
```

And ticked the lamp option.
For some reason this angle worked. Though I cannot tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to remove `MySQL` and re-install it:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

If you want you can backup everything first:

```
/usr/sbin/service mysql stop
cp -rf /var/lib/mysql/* "~/BACKUPS/MySQL/"
/usr/sbin/service mysql start
```

Comment: FYI, there is no suck package as `mysql`. What you meant is probably `mysql-server`.