# MySQL Installation Issues on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: server, permissions, dpkg, mysql, lamp

Firstly, I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 (Velvet) on my local machine.

I recently uninstalled the LAMP stack due to several config issues I was experiencing (especially when I tried working with CodeIgniter). Wasn't sure if it were from PHP or Apache. But I know I'd done several edit configs on my PHP & Apache files of which I had forgotten where & when. Unistalling it all was the only option I could think of.

Now, I was re-installing the stack following the official guide [on Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). While installing, I came across a few issues.

Screen shots are available [here](https://goo.gl/XxqSzx).

**First Issue**

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.6.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb ...
grep: /etc/mysql/: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: Unit mysql.service is masked
```

mysql.service is masked. Does it mean inaccessible?

**Second Issue**

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: Unit mysql.service is masked
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up libalgorithm-c3-perl (0.09-1) ...
```

It repeated same *invoke* error as the first. But this time there was an additional file path & dpkg error

**Thrid Issue**

```
Setting up libtext-template-perl (1.46-1) ...
Setting up libsoftware-license-perl (0.103010-3) ...
Setting up libterm-ui-perl (0.42-1) ...
Setting up libtext-soundex-perl (3.4-1build2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up rename (0.20-3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/file-rename to provide /usr/bin/rename (rename) in auto mode
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.04-1) ...
```

Same dpkg error. Seems like it couldn't access a folder, it had to create its own and named it 'rename'

**Fourth Issue**

```
Module mpm_event disabled.
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
apache2_switch_mpm Switch to prefork
apache2_invoke: Enable module php5
Setting up apache2-mpm-prefork (2.4.10-9ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was hoping this fourth one is only a summary of the previous 3 errors, but I wasn't sure.

Like mentioned, I'm a novice in Linux. I don't want to mess with any file or folder so I don't screw it up like I always end up doing.

Seems like it all has to do with file access & permission.

If so, **how then can I solve this thing please?** *It's really killing me*. I have always had file permission issues trying to access folders (especially) within *'/var/lib'*.

If not so, **what could be the possible issue, and how can I solve it?**

THANK YOU!

Comment: Similar thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/614551/how-to-get-mysql-server-setup-on-ubuntu-15-04 check whether this could hep you with dpkg.

Comment: @vembutech I already tried that, it doesn't entirely solve the issue. "mysql-common" wasnt purged... It displayed a dpkg error. The "invoke-rc.d: Unit MySQL.service is masked" error still existed.

Comment: @vembutech after giving it another try using tasksel, I got an error: "aptitude failed (100)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue.

After several trial & error, what I did was:

1. I rolled back an earlier backup (2 months old)
2. I re-tried installing lamp sever using:

   ```
   sudo tasksel install lamp-server
   ```

This helped me identify the missing directories.

3. I manually created the missing folders in the mysql directory
4. Next, I ran these commands

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server 
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.6
   ```
5. I manually installed every other important php5 & mysql packages

Somehow, this worked for me. I'm not sure where I did it right, & if it has no side effect... so I don't advise anyone having similar issue to follow what I just out-laid.

However, you could keep exploring till you a get a fix. Document it, so in future you know exactly how you handled it in the past.

Comment: About 4 years later and this still cracks me up. Well, good times. :)